# Avoid special values or space between values using python re

Tags: python

For any phone number which allows `()` in the area code and any space between area code and the 4th number, I want to create a tuple of the 3 sets of numbers.

For example: `(301)  556-9018` or `(301)556-9018` would return `('301','556','9018')`.
I will raise a Value error exception if the input is anything other than the original format.

How do I avoid `()` characters and include either `\s` or none between the area code and the next values?

This is my foundation so far:

```
phonenum=re.compile('''([\d)]+)\s([\d]+) - ([\d]+)$''',re.VERBOSE).match('(123) 324244-123').groups()
print(phonenum)
```

Do I need to make a if then statement to ignore the () for the first tuple element, or is there a re expression that does that more efficiently?

In addition the `\s` in between the first 2 tuples doesn't work if it's `(301)556-9018`.

Any hints on how to approach this?

Comment: Umm... `re.findall(r'\d{3,4}')`

Comment: `'(\d){3}\s*.?\s*(\d{3})\s*.?\s*(\d{4})'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying a regular expression, you should use *raw-string* mode:

```
`r'abc'` instead of `'abc'`
```

That said, right now you are *capturing* three sets of numbers in *groups*. To allow parens, you will need to match parens. (The parens you currently have are for the capturing groups.)

You can match parens by escaping them: `\(` and `\)`

You can find various solutions to "what is a regex for XXX" by seaching one of the many "regex libary" web sites. I was able to find this one via DuckDuckGo:  http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone

To make a part of your pattern optional, you can make the individual pieces optional, or you can provide alternatives with the piece present or absent.

Since the parens have to be present or absent together - that is, you don't want to allow an opening paren but no closing paren - you probably want to provide alternatives:

```
# number, no parens: 800 555-1212
noparens = r'\d{3}\s+\d{3}-\d{4}'

# number with parens:  (800) 555-1212
yesparens = r'\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4}'
```

You can match the three pieces by inserting "grouping parens":

```
noparens_grouped = r'(\d{3})\s+(\d{3})-(\d{4})'
yesparens_grouped = r'\((\d{3})\)\s*(\d{3})-(\d{4})'
```

Note that the quoted parens go *outside* of the grouping parens, so that the parens do not become part of the captured group.

You can join the alternatives together with the `|` operator:

```
yes_or_no_parens_groups = noparens_grouped + '|' + yesparens_grouped
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was stupidly putting \( and \) next to each other after the \d.

Comment: How do I adjust the re if only a space is allowed before the 2nd grouping of numbers is area code has (). ?  i.e. 301 888-9999 will give an error, but (301) xxx-xxxx or 301-xxx xxxx is fine.  r'\s*\(*(\d{3})\)*\-*\s*(\d{3})\-*(\d{4})\s*'

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions you can use special characters to specify some behavior of some part of the expression.
From python re documentation:

> '*' =
>       Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. ab* will match ‘a’, ‘ab’, or ‘a’ followed by any number of ‘b’s.
>
> '+' =
>       Causes the resulting RE to match 1 or more repetitions of the preceding RE. ab+ will match ‘a’ followed by any non-zero number of ‘b’s; it will not match just ‘a’.
>
> '?' =
>       Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE. ab? will match either ‘a’ or ‘ab’.

So to solve the blank space problem you can use either '?' if you know the occurrence will be no more than 1, or '+' if you can have more than 1.

In case of grouping information together and them returning a list, you can put your expression inside parenthesis and then use function groups() from re.
The result would be:

```
results = re.search('\((\d{3})\)\s?(\d{3})-(\d{4})', '(301) 556-9018')
if results:
  print results.groups()
else:
  print('Invalid phone number')
```